# Checking for multiple records based on the value of a VARCHAR column

Tags: sql, db2

I am trying to find if there is a Party ID that has multiple FACTORY records.  For instance, there is party ID(parent) which has a one to many relationship to Factory ID (child).  The way to find out the factory ID for a party ID is based on a VARCHAR column called TYPE, and where TYPE = 'FACTORY' (multiple values of TYPE exist) you can obtain the Party Id that has that Factory.  I am trying to grab the party ID's where the TYPE = 'FACTORY' and where TYPE FACTORY is greater than 1.

I am doing a

```
SELECT PARTY_ID
FROM TABLE X 
WHERE TYPE = 'FACTORY' AND
      (insert condition to check for TYPE = 'FACTORY' having count > 1
```

for that Party ID.  I can't seem to come up with the syntax for it.  
If anyone has any suggestions I would appreciate it.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `GROUP BY` and `HAVING`:

```
SELECT PARTY_ID
FROM TABLE X
WHERE TYPE = 'FACTORY'
GROUP BY PARTY_ID
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
```